# Как организовать работу с socket с gprs терминалом?

Tags: javascript, сокет

Поделитесь опытом пожалуйста.
JavaScript
Создал tcp сервер с помощью net из node.
Есть gprs терминал Teleofis, при первом подключении отправляю запрос на авторизацию, получаю ответ, если он верный, отправляю подтверждение авторизации. Сам сокет сохраняю в список активных клиентов.
К самому терминалу подключено разное оборудование, которое будет опрашиваться отдельно по запросу.
Я могу сокет отправить в отдельную функцию, но все равно socket.on("data") будет отрабатывать в одном месте, и я не могу тут сделать проверку от какого оборудования пришел ответ.
Как в моем случае организовать опрос оборудования?
Наброски кода в [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/gprs-terminal-8h62nd?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A24%2C3-24%2C19)

```
const net = require("net");
const server = net.createServer();
const activeClients = [];
// создаю tcp сервер для подключения gprs терминалов, к которым подключено оборудование
server.listen(
  {
    port: 1015,
    host: "localhost",
    exclusive: true,
  },
  () => {
    console.log("Сервер запущен на ", server.address());
    console.log("Сервер запущен в ", Date());
  },
);

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  soketConnection({ socket });
});

function soketConnection({ socket }) {
  socket.write(/*отправляю запрос на первое соединение*/);

  socket.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (/*если пришел пакет от модема*/ true) {
      // socket записываю в текущие клиенты
      activeClients.push(socket);
      socket.write(/*отправляю подтверждение соединения*/);
    } else {
      console.log("пакет пришел от оборудования");
      /* допустим я тут вызову функцию, которая обработает данные от устройства, но данные будут от разных устройств и по пакету я не могу их проверить*/
      // нужно как-то перенести чтение приходящих данных в отдельную функцию, которая будет вызываться при необходимости и при опросе конкретного оборудования
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: А по каким признакам вы в принципе собираетесь узнавать, от какого оборудования пришёл ответ?

Comment: от gprs терминала в начале и конце пакета всегда 0xC0 и 0xC2, все остальные данные я должен получать только в функции, в которой опрашиваю конкретное оборудование (в моем случае счетчик эл. энергии)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае нужно использовать socket.once
`socket.once("data", (data) => { console.log(data);}`